# Django app with mysql support not working when deployed to GCP

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create sample Django app with MySQL as database, its working fine in local when same app I try to deploy on GCP gives 500 error.
I have created sql server in GCP and sued same settings

Its failing to find `gunicorn` but I have specified all this in `requirments.txt`.

```
2019-01-19 07:42:57 default[20190119t130429]  "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 500
2019-01-19 07:42:58 default[20190119t130429]  /bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found
2019-01-23 17:41:21 default[20190119t130429]  "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 500
2019-01-23 17:41:22 default[20190119t130429]  /bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found
2019-01-23 18:36:00 default[20190123t235752]  "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 500
2019-01-23 18:36:00 default[20190123t235752]  /bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found
2019-01-23 18:36:01 default[20190123t235752]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500
2019-01-23 18:36:02 default[20190123t235752]  /bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found
2019-01-23 18:36:20 default[20190123t235752]  "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 500
2019-01-23 18:36:20 default[20190123t235752]  /bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found
2019-01-23 18:36:21 default[20190123t235752]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500
2019-01-23 18:36:21 default[20190123t235752]  /bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found
```

```
**app.yaml**

runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT sqlreco.wsgi
#threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'

runtime_config:
 python_version: 3
```

```
**requirnaments.txt**

Django==2.1.5
djangorestframework==3.9.1
mysql==0.0.2
mysqlclient==1.4.1
pytz==2018.9
gunicorn==19.8.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

It looks like you don't have a `main.py` file for your application. If you're not specifying a custom entrypoint, you need to have this file with a variable named `app` which corresponds to your application.

For Django, you can probably just do something like this in `main.py`:

```
from mysite.wsgi import application as app
```

Where `mysite` is the name of the directory that your Django app lives in.

Comment: The has done already that error was old one I have updated the log in question removing the older logs

Comment: Can you include your `app.yaml` and your `requirements.txt` in the question?

Comment: added the app.yaml and requirements.txt

Comment: Is your file literally called `requirnaments.txt`? There's a typo there, it might explain why `gunicorn` is not getting installed.